# Get-ChildItem different commands

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

What is the difference between the  following commands in PowerShell?

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory

Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}
```

They both seem to give the same results. Is there a difference at all?

Update:

I have just started learning powershell and I am not familiar with most of terminology. The results on both commands are like the following:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----          7.9.2021     22.35                Administrator
d-----          7.9.2021     15.40                MyDevice
d-r---          6.5.2020     11.59                Public
d-----          7.9.2021     22.45                student
```

Comment: Yes, you're using the pipeline to filter using `Where-Object` (*a separate cmdlet*) rather than the switch available for you just using `Get-ChildItem`. Generally, you want to filter as far left as possible. The pipeline slows down "*stuff*", and some cmdlets provide filters and switches that let you filter at the beginning stage.

Comment: There was a time before PowerShell version 3.0 when we did not have the parameter `-Directory`. That's why you still find the old version of filtering for only folders. ;-)

Comment: Ahhh yes, forgot to mention what Olaf just did! Stick to the new way, and always follow the general rule of filtering as far left as possible

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. @AbrahamZinala would you kindly tell me what do you mean by "filtering  as far left as possible"?

Comment: Instead of: `Get-ChildItem C:\Users | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}`,  do this: `Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory`. Certain cmdlets offer filtering options that you can use to avoid using the pipeline, which will help in performance speed.

Comment: Or: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\users\MyName\Desktop' -Filter '*.txt' -Recurse` instead of this: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\users\MyName\Desktop' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.txt'}`. You get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's great information in the comments; let me try to distill and complement it:

- `Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true }` (or, better, `Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }`) for limiting [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s output to *directories* as well as `Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }` for limiting output to *files* were **only needed up to the (long obsolete) v2** of PowerShell, as [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) points out.
- **v3** introduced the dynamic **`-Directory` and `-File`** switch parameters to `Get-ChildItem` to allow direct filtering of the output to directories / files only.

*Functionally*, the two commands in your question are equivalent, but **use of `-File` / `-Directory` is not only more concise, but also *faster***, because needing to involve *two* commands in the pipeline invariably adds overhead.

- As [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) advises, **it is always preferable to filter at the *source***, which is what `-File` and `-Directory` do; so does the `-Filter` parameter, for limiting output to items whose name matches a wildcard pattern such as `*.txt` (other cmdlets also support (command-specific) `-Filter` arguments, and they're always worth using, as they improve performance both in terms of execution speed and memory use).

**Note**: Strictly speaking, **the commands are only equivalent for *file-system paths***, whereas PowerShell's drive concept also encompasses other types of data stores, via so-called [*providers*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers).

It is only the `FileSystem` provider that exposes the `-Directory` and `-File` switches (as so-called [*dynamic parameters*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#dynamic-parameters)).

So for a path related to a *different* provider - assuming that that provider has an object hierarchy analogous to file-systems involving *two item subtypes*, *leaf* items (analogous to *files*) and *container* items (analogous to *directories*) - a separate cmdlet call such as `Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }` may still be needed - unless that provider implements its own analog to the `-Directory` and `-File` switches.

Among the providers that ship with PowerShell, the distinction between container and leaf items applies only to the WSMan (drive `wsman:`) and Certificate providers (drive `cert:`); the other providers only expose a *single* item type, either because their data is *non-hierarchical* (e.g., the `Env` provider - try `Get-ChildItem Env:`) or because other entities are exposed as *properties* rather than as *items* (the `Registry` provider, which exposes *containers only* - registry *keys* - whereas the registry *values* are *properties* of those containers).